# SQLite inner join 2 tables into a main table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a main table that looks like

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS filesystem (
    inode           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    uid             TEXT, 
    gid             TEXT, 
    type            TEXT,
    pathname        TEXT,
    parentinode     INTEGER,
    FileCounter     INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    DirCounter      INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    TotalByteSum    INTEGER DEFAULT 0 )
```

and 2 sub tables that look like:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (
    gid         TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    groupname   TEXT

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    uid         TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    username    TEXT
```

Currently I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE completeFileSystem AS SELECT filesystem.inode, users.username, groups.groupname, filesystem.type,  filesystem.pathname,filesystem.parentinode, filesystem.FileCounter, filesystem.DirCounter, filesystem.TotalByteSum
FROM filesystem 
INNER JOIN users ON filesystem.uid = users.uid 
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.gid = filesystem.gid
```

that creates a new table which results in my db file being larger than desired.

I would like to inner join on filesystem.uid = users.uid and on filesystem.gid = groups.gid into the filesystem table directly. Is this possible in SQLite? I am using Python to script these sql statements if that changes anything.

Comment: Er yes, just do the SELECT without the CREATE TABLE, surely?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman That would inner join it on one query. I want my gid and uid column to be updated directly in the filesystem table in order to be able to perform multiple queries later

Comment: Sounds like you want a [view](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html), then.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman : Do you know how Views will perform with a large data set? I am working with over 30 million entries in my db and it seems like have a table set with the desired columns inner joined will perform faster than a query on a View since to my understanding a view is just a shortcut to a Select statement. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: i think you're going to have to decide: do you want those users/groups tables separate or not?

Comment: @CaiusJard I am just looking for the fastest solution since my data set is quite large. In this case, which would be the optimal route to take?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean when you say "fastest solution" - you haven't really said what you're trying to achieve so we can't say what the fastest way to achieve it is! one thing is often sure about people seeking the "fastest" anything on db related questions: tha mount of time we spend chewing, and anguishing and perftesting sample queries on here, if the first sub optimal solution had just been written and left going while we chew over it.. it would be done way before we reached consensus!

Comment: @CaiusJard I see! My end goal is to be able to perform some dynamic queries while users on the frontend intereacts with a D3.js based graph with the on-click type of loading. I am looking to minimize as much as possible the waiting time for each query therefore from my understanding having a premade table containing all the required data is the way to go. Please correct me if in this case, another solution is more optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a view for this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW completeFileSystem AS
SELECT ...
FROM filesystem 
JOIN users USING (uid)
JOIN groups USING (gid);
```

This is usually fast enough. (You can speed it up a little bit by making the two lookup tables [WITHOUT ROWID tables](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html).)
If the main table has very many rows, the space saved by storing only the user/group IDs will, and thus reduced I/O, can compensate for the effort of doing the joins.

Whether this is actually fast enough for your particular application is something you have to measure yourself.